# Abrir arquivo em C

Tags: c, arquivo

Gostaria de saber como eu faço para abrir um arquivo em C (Abrir mesmo, como se tivesse dado duplo-click), pq da forma que eu fiz, o programa diz que o arquivo foi aberto, mas ele não é aberto de fato.

Caso a linguagem C não possa fazer isso, qual linguagem eu posso usar?

Código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

  FILE *arquivo = fopen("c:\\eu.txt", "r");// testa se o arquivo foi aberto com sucesso

  if(arquivo != NULL)
    printf("Arquivo foi aberto com sucesso.");
  else
    printf("Nao foi possivel abrir o arquivo.");

  printf("\n\n");
  system("PAUSE");
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Como assim duplo-clique? Você quer carregar o conteúdo do arquivo ou você quer exibir o conteúdo do arquivo com o gerenciador daquele determinado tipo de arquivo?

Comment: Se aparecer a mensagem "Arquivo foi aberto com sucesso." então ele está aberto. Se além disso você quiser exibir o conteúdo deste arquivo então terá que incluir em seu programa os comandos adequados para isso e, ao final, não esquecer de fechar o arquivo aberto.

Answer (score 0):

Na verdade, utilizando o `fopen`, você terá um ponteiro para o arquivo, então você poderá trabalhar com o conteúdo desse arquivo (ler e escrever no arquivo, por exemplo).

Caso você queira abrir o arquivo com a aplicação padrão, vamos supor um Bloco de Notas, você pode usar as funções [execl](https://linux.die.net/man/3/execl) ou [system](https://linux.die.net/man/3/system).

Atualmente eu não consego testá-los no windows, mas creio que deva funcionar também.